# How to get submitted data in Sprout Forms custom email

Tags: plugin-sproutforms

I've setup a custom email notification that is sent out after submitting a form. I want to have a set message but with a personalised greeting "Hi Bob". I have the email.html file and that works but I can't figure out how to display the persons name. In my example the field handle it yourName and the form handle is contactForm.

Is this possible?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Following Sprout Forms example templates (*/admin/sproutemail/settings/examples*): in your email.html file `Hi {{ object['yourName'] }}` or even `Hi {{ object.yourName }}`, should print `Hi Bob`.

Comment: Thanks. In the end I found that {{ element.yourName }} worked. Not sure if object and element are interchangeable? But thanks for the reply!

Comment: I think it doesn't matter, and even {{ yourName }} should works as a shorthand.